# Using same variable names and overwriting in scriptblock

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a script that imports CSV files, formats them (remove certain columns and rows, adds new columns etc) and then exports them back to disk. The processing is such a way that I had to do two import-csv/export-csv on the same files. Here is a code snippet :

```
# Formating 1:
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $fileSource -Filter *.csv
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # do my formating tasks 1...
    Export-Csv $file.FullName -Force -NoTypeInformation
}

# Formating 2:
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $fileSource -Filter *.csv
foreach ($file in  $files) {
    # do my formating tasks 2
    Export-Csv $file.FullName -Force -NoTypeInformation
}
```

**Question**

Is it "OK" to use the same variable names (i.e. `$files`/`$file`) in the same script block and overwrite the values as in my case above?

Comment: It's OK as long as you use them in exactly that way (`$files` for the list of items to process and `$file` as the loop variable) and don't nest one loop inside the other.

Comment: thanks Ansgar, that answers my question. How can I mark your response as the answer please?